# is it possible to set the UILabel distance between the line?

Tags: iphone, uilabel, line-spacing

Is it possible to set a UILabel's distance between the line, as i had a UILabel contain 3 lines, and linebreakmode is wordwrap?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880526/how-to-increase-a-space-between-two-lines-in-multiline-label

Answer (score 6):

If you're referring to "leading", which refers to the gap between lines of type - you cannot change this on a UILabel. That is inferred from the front of the label itself. Some people have tried to create categories to override the "leading" property of the UIFont for the label but it doesn't actually work when rendering.

If you really need to control the vertical spacing between lines of text then your best bet is to programmatically drop 1 UILabel per line of fixed width and control the vertical gap yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can set line spacing using interface builder and programatically as well.

**From Interface Builder:**

[image]

**Programmatically:**

**SWift 4**

Using label extension

```
extension UILabel {

    // Pass value for any one of both parameters and see result
    func setLineSpacing(lineSpacing: CGFloat = 0.0, lineHeightMultiple: CGFloat = 0.0) {

        guard let labelText = self.text else { return }

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
        paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeightMultiple

        let attributedString:NSMutableAttributedString
        if let labelattributedText = self.attributedText {
            attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: labelattributedText)
        } else {
            attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: labelText)
        }

        // Line spacing attribute
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

        self.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```

Now call extension function

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "is\nit\npossible\nto\nset\nthe\nUILabel\ndistance\nbetween\nthe\nline?"

// Pass value for any one argument - lineSpacing or lineHeightMultiple
label.setLineSpacing(lineSpacing: 2.0) .  // try values 1.0 to 5.0

// or try lineHeightMultiple
//label.setLineSpacing(lineHeightMultiple = 2.0) // try values 0.5 to 2.0
```

Or using label instance (Just copy & execute this code to see result)

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "is\nit\npossible\nto\nset\nthe\nUILabel\ndistance\nbetween\nthe\nline?"
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
var style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 24 // change line spacing between paragraph like 36 or 48
style.minimumLineHeight = 20 // change line spacing between each line like 30 or 40

// Line spacing attribute
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringValue.characters.count))

// Character spacing attribute
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

label.attributedText = attrString
```