# Set UILabel line spacing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, multiline, line-spacing

How can I modify the gap between lines (line spacing) in a multiline `UILabel`?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

**Edit:** Evidently `NSAttributedString` will do it, on iOS 6 and later. Instead of using an `NSString` to set the label's text, create an `NSAttributedString`, set attributes on it, then set it as the `.attributedText` on the label. The code you want will be something like this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString  alloc] initWithString:@"Sample text"];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[style setLineSpacing:24];
[attrString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
    value:style
    range:NSMakeRange(0, strLength)];
uiLabel.attributedText = attrString;
```

NSAttributedString's old attributedStringWithString did the same thing, but now *that* is being deprecated.

For historical reasons, here's my original answer:

**Short answer:** you can't. To change the spacing between lines of text, you will have to subclass `UILabel` and roll your own `drawTextInRect`, create multiple labels, or use a different font (perhaps one edited for a specific line height, see Phillipe's answer).

**Long answer:** In the print and online world, the space between lines of text is known as "leading" (rhymes with 'heading', and comes from the lead metal used decades ago). Leading is a read-only property of `UIFont`, which was deprecated in 4.0 and replaced by `lineHeight`. As far as I know, there's no way to create a font with a specific set of parameters such as `lineHeight`; you get the system fonts and any custom font you add, but can't tweak them once installed.

There is no spacing parameter in `UILabel`, either.

I'm not particularly happy with `UILabel`'s behavior as is, so I suggest writing your own subclass or using a 3rd-party library. That will make the behavior independent of your font choice and be the most reusable solution.

I wish there *was* more flexibility in `UILabel`, and I'd be happy to be proven wrong!

Comment: I have done it with sub-classing UILabel, basically idea is to divide label text into tokens, and then identity length of each token, create a separate label for each token and append one after another. Thats it.

Comment: Lies! ;) You can patch a font file to change the line height - see my answer on this page.

Comment: I'm [led to believe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8162907/1167833) there's a way to do this with NSAttributedString. If you need labels with attributed strings in pre iOS 6, check out [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel).

Comment: Do it with NSAttributesString if you use iOS >= 6. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19258637/832111)

Comment: This is Simple and Working Fine.

Answer (score 75):

Starting in ios 6 you can set an attributed string in the UILabel:

```
NSString *labelText = @"some text"; 
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:labelText];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle setLineSpacing:40];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [labelText length])];
cell.label.attributedText = attributedString ;
```

Comment: thanks! i'd add that using `AttributedString` disables for example label's text alignment, so you have to add it to the paragraph style.

Answer (score 56):

You can control line spacing in the storyboard:

[image]

[duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494498/how-to-control-the-line-spacing-in-uilabel/26044421#26044421)

Comment: However in Xcode 6.1.1 selecting the label and changing the line value in the attributed panel will cause the panel to flicker and lock the application. I have only been able to exit the panel by force-quitting Xcode.

Comment: Thumbs up for the animation

Comment: In version 7.1 the panel flicks and it doesn't have any effect on run time. Had to do it in code.

Comment: 440 watt electricity ran through my panel just now ;)

Answer (score 24):

**From Interface Builder:**

[image]

**Programmatically:**

**SWift 4**

Using label extension

```
extension UILabel {

    func setLineSpacing(lineSpacing: CGFloat = 0.0, lineHeightMultiple: CGFloat = 0.0) {

        guard let labelText = self.text else { return }

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
        paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeightMultiple

        let attributedString:NSMutableAttributedString
        if let labelattributedText = self.attributedText {
            attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: labelattributedText)
        } else {
            attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: labelText)
        }

        // Line spacing attribute
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

        self.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```

Now call extension function

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "How to\ncontrol\nthe\nline spacing\nin UILabel"

// Pass value for any one argument - lineSpacing or lineHeightMultiple
label.setLineSpacing(lineSpacing: 2.0) .  // try values 1.0 to 5.0

// or try lineHeightMultiple
//label.setLineSpacing(lineHeightMultiple = 2.0) // try values 0.5 to 2.0
```

Or using label instance (Just copy & execute this code to see result)

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "Set\nUILabel\nline\nspacing"
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
var style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 24 // change line spacing between paragraph like 36 or 48
style.minimumLineHeight = 20 // change line spacing between each line like 30 or 40

// Line spacing attribute
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringValue.characters.count))

// Character spacing attribute
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

label.attributedText = attrString
```

**Swift 3**

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "Set\nUILabel\nline\nspacing"
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
var style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 24 // change line spacing between paragraph like 36 or 48
style.minimumLineHeight = 20 // change line spacing between each line like 30 or 40
attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringValue.characters.count))
label.attributedText = attrString
```

Comment: Need to pass only one arguement lineSpacing or multipleLineheight , can t pass both arguenemt other wise no result will come, i think

Answer (score 16):

My solution was to patch the font file itself and fix its line height definitely.
http://mbauman.net/geek/2009/03/15/minor-truetype-font-editing-on-a-mac/

I had to modify 'lineGap', 'ascender', 'descender' in the 'hhea' block (as in the blog example).

Comment: Super cool! Those OS X font tools also worked for my OTF font (although it only specifies TTF...). My font had line-height 1000 (!), I changed it to 0 and voila. I had miles and miles of empty space below the text on each line.

Comment: I can't believe this is the best solution (no offense!), but it is by far the simplest.  I used the free (Windows) software [Type Light](http://www.cr8software.net/typelight.html) (and under Font | Metrics | Advanced you can modify lineGap) to edit my fonts.  It also allows you to "rename" the fonts, which I couldn't figure out how to do using the tool Philippe mentioned.

Comment: Also see my answer to a similar question for more specifics: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19553827/201828

Comment: @iamjustaprogrammer It's online again.

Comment: The link is dead, again.

Answer (score 8):

This guy created a class to get line-height (without using CoreText, as MTLabel library) : https://github.com/LemonCake/MSLabel

Answer (score 7):

Best thing I found is: https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

It's a UILabel subclass so you can just drop it in, and then to change the line height:

```
myLabel.lineHeightMultiple = 0.85;
myLabel.leading = 2;
```

Answer (score 4):

I've found 3rd Party Libraries Like this one:

https://github.com/Tuszy/MTLabel

To be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some swift-code for you to set the line spacing programmatically

```
let label = UILabel()

let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your string")
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

//SET THIS:
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 4
//OR SET THIS:
paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 4

//Or set both :)

let range = NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length)
attributedText.addAttributes([NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle], range: range)
label.attributedText = attributedText
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, Mike's answer doesn't work if you pass the string programmatically. In this case you need to pass a attributed string and change it's style.

```
NSMutableAttributedString * attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your \nregular \nstring"];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[style setLineSpacing:4];
[attrString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                   value:style
                   range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length)];
_label.attributedText = attrString;
```