# Font Issue in iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am working with custom fonts. it is working fine with iPhone

```
            [btnHourMins.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Rockwell-Bold" size:18]];
            [txtPrice setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Rockwell-Bold" size:18]];
```

but when i used it in iPad then it display strange behavior (see in image), it display only half of the textbox an button.**No any type of frame of button or textField set by me.**

[image]

my coding for ipad is

```
      [txtPrice setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Rockwell-Bold" size:36]];
      [lblHourMins.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Rockwell-Bold" size:36]];
```

and if i set the size 10 instead of 36 it works fine. I download font from heare  http://www.freefontsdb.com/detail/8042/Rockwell-Bold  How can i solved this Problem. I searched from last 2 days.

1) No any type of view above on UITextField of UIButton
2) NO any type of frame set by me in coding (I just set the font).
3) Size of the Textfield and button is very bigger.

When i set backgroundclour Pink it display ...

[image]

Comment: Here is a [question] [1] similar to yours. Maybe it will help.

[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741222/uilabel-with-custom-font-wrongly-rendered

Comment: Have you tried with other fonts? Sometimes it will be the problem with the font.

Comment: Can you tell me the height of the label my friend???

Comment: @NiravPatel PinkColor is height of textbox and button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution. its the problem of font file when i tried with this

http://www.2shared.com/file/DEGKglFX/ROCKB.html

It working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the frame of your label isn't tall enough for the size of the font.

You will need to adjust the height to see the full text, or have it shrink the fontsize based on what will fit in the label.

Edit:
Sorry I didn't see the additional text after your picture. Can you verify that the view is big enough? Try setting the background color to see it's frame.

Comment: Thanks for answer, my TextField size is very big...i try with it 100 height but not working

Comment: If you use a standard iOS font in the same place does everything work right?