# Fixing horizontal alignment for custom installed font in iPhone apps

Tags: objective-c, fonts, uifont

I am trying to use Helvetica Condensed font in my app. I've overcome problems with it's vertical alignment, by adjusting ascender (as described in this answer).

However, I also have problems with horizontal alignment - the text in UILabel keeps shifting right a bit when text is aligned left (the "length" of the shift depends on how much text is in the label).

I believe it could be solved using the same technique but I don't know which parameter I should adjust.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8314285/963881

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just move the label without editing the ascender, you could adjust the UIButton contentEdgetInsets property.

```
yourButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, 0, 0);
```

This line of code would move your label to the right. The inputs are different from CGRects in that it goes (top, left, bottom, right).

Might be a bit of a hack, but it works.