# Embedded Font not positioned properly in iOS

Tags: ios

[image]

Hi, I have a problem using embedded fonts in iOS.

The UILabel doesn't display it properly.

It should be centred vertically and horizontally.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem with the picture? What should be different?

Comment: It doesn't position the text properly. as if there's some padding at the top. the font size is already set to 139 points.

Comment: Can you add that to your question, please? Be specific and detailed about the issue as you see it.

Answer (score 0):

For VerticalAlignment.

```
YourLabel.textAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```

Centered both vertically and horizontally.

```
theYourLabel.textAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
theYourLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

**Another way is :**

```
YourYourLabelName.center = parentViewField.center;
```

**OR**

```
YourLabel = [[UIYourLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake("As You Want")];
YourLabel.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(someView.bounds)/2.0f, CGRectGetHeight(someView.bounds)/2.0f);
```

**OR**

alternative you can use `UITextField`, the subclass of `UIControl`, which inherits UIControl's the `contentVerticalAlignment` property.

```
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
```

You can use this property to align the text on top. **You can disable the user from editing** the text by using the property `userInteractionEnabled` property.

Comment: I've tried using UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter. It doesn't work. unfortunately, UITextAlignmentCenter is also deprecated in iOS6

Comment: ok, I'll keep on testing. thanks for your answers ! really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases custom fonts cannot be positioned properly by iOS controls such as UILabels, UIButtons etc without patching the font file itself. Please see the following question for more info:

[Custom installed font not displayed correctly in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414730/custom-installed-font-not-displayed-correctly-in-uilabel)

One of the answers suggested using `ftxdumperfuser` tool provided by Apple to change the `ascender` property of the font file - that solved the similar issue with custom font in my app.

Comment: ok, I'll have a look. thanks. your answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure about dfont font format, been using ttf fonts for my app. If the font format does not matter, you could try converting your dfont to ttf using some of the online converters and then patch the resulted ttf if necessary.

Comment: Heheh, thanks for your reply, I've got it working. it also accepts .dfont format.