# iOS 7 Custom UILabel Font, text beyond the edges of the label

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, arabic, xcode5, uifont

Since iOS 7 , Arabic fonts are now supported, but when i use the:

```
   lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Scheherazade" size:33];
```

The text reaches the edges of the `UILabel` and some of the words cannot be read !!

How to fix this problem?? here is describing my problem.[image: A Picture]

here is my code:

```
lbl  = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 280, 320)];
lbl.text = @"شِّرِ ٱلَّذِينَ ءَامَنُوا۟ وَعَمِلُوا۟ ٱلصَّٰلِحَٰتِ أَنَّ لَهُمْ جَنَّٰتٍۢ تَجْرِى مِن تَحْتِهَا ٱلْأَنْهَٰرُ ۖ كُلَّمَا رُزِقُوا۟ مِنْهَا مِن ثَمَرَةٍۢ رِّزْقًۭا ۙ قَالُوا۟ هَٰذَا ٱلَّذِى رُزِقْنَا مِن قَبْلُ ۖ وَأُتُوا۟ بِهِۦ مُتَشَٰبِهًۭا ۖ وَلَهُمْ فِيهَآ أَزْوَٰجٌۭ مُّطَهَّرَةٌۭ ۖ وَهُمْ فِيهَا خَٰلِدُونَ";
lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Scheherazade" size:33.0];
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
[self.view addSubview:lbl];
lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Comment: have you tried to change the alignment ?

Comment: Yes , i tried the Center, L & R, i tried all the lineBreakModes but still have the same problem

Comment: `CGSize stringSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Scheherazade" size:33.0]
                              constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 320) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];`
Try to dynamically set width and height of your label

Comment: Thats not my problem, the label is text font size may be changed during the app running

Comment: font rendering on ios7 is broken in so many places... tell me if you find an answer ;)

Comment: @Daij-Djan i hope to find

Comment: Did you find the solution to your problem @Mutawe ? I am having same problem and its not even resolved in iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same issue in iOS 7. I think there is a bug where `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping` is **always** treated as `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`. I have submitted to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem where my custom font was cut off on the bottom (especially in iOS 7), and I found a few answers on this post to be quite helpful where I edited the font file directly and changed the ascender and/or descender attributes.

[Custom installed font not displayed correctly in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414730/custom-installed-font-not-displayed-correctly-in-uilabel/)

In your case there might be other attributes in that font file that you can edit to prevent it from being cut off on the left and ride sides.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `UILabel`'s `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to the width of its superview (optionally with a left/right padding).

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the line break mode "NSLineBreakByWordWrapping". I think it issue occurs due to arabic text.

UILabel * lbl  = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 280, 320)];

```
lbl.text = @"شِّرِ ٱلَّذِينَ ءَامَنُوا۟ وَعَمِلُوا۟ ٱلصَّٰلِحَٰتِ أَنَّ لَهُمْ جَنَّٰتٍۢ تَجْرِى مِن تَحْتِهَا ٱلْأَنْهَٰرُ ۖ كُلَّمَا رُزِقُوا۟ مِنْهَا مِن ثَمَرَةٍۢ رِّزْقًۭا ۙ قَالُوا۟ هَٰذَا ٱلَّذِى رُزِقْنَا مِن قَبْلُ ۖ وَأُتُوا۟ بِهِۦ مُتَشَٰبِهًۭا ۖ وَلَهُمْ فِيهَآ أَزْوَٰجٌۭ مُّطَهَّرَةٌۭ ۖ وَهُمْ فِيهَا خَٰلِدُونَ";
lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Scheherazade" size:33.0];
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor white];
lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[self.view addSubview:lbl];
lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score -2):

Find your problem actually font size was not channing with your `lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Scheherazade" size:33.0];` try to adjust your font size with this code

lbl.font= [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];

I have updated my code and now i am able to see complete text

```
UILabel *lbl  = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 280, 320)];
lbl.text = @"شِّرِ ٱلَّذِينَ ءَامَنُوا۟ وَعَمِلُوا۟ ٱلصَّٰلِحَٰتِ أَنَّ لَهُمْ جَنَّٰتٍۢ تَجْرِى مِن تَحْتِهَا ٱلْأَنْهَٰرُ ۖ كُلَّمَا رُزِقُوا۟ مِنْهَا مِن ثَمَرَةٍۢ رِّزْقًۭا ۙ قَالُوا۟ هَٰذَا ٱلَّذِى رُزِقْنَا مِن قَبْلُ ۖ وَأُتُوا۟ بِهِۦ مُتَشَٰبِهًۭا ۖ وَلَهُمْ فِيهَآ أَزْوَٰجٌۭ مُّطَهَّرَةٌۭ ۖ وَهُمْ فِيهَا خَٰلِدُونَ";
lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Scheherazade" size:33.0];
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
[self.view addSubview:lbl];
lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

[image: screentshot]

Comment: have you added the font to your project  @"Scheherazade" font??