# Custom font is not set properly in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uifont

I am using custom font in my application. I have set this to label, button and textfield. But when I used the custom font then text alignment of all object is changed. Its display from top side.

Here is the label with default font :

[image]

Here is the label with Custom font :

[image]

Here is the code :

```
    lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueLTStd-ThCn" size:[lbl.font pointSize]]];
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Each font has its kerning & pattern. You should fine tune the text appearance by re-positioning the label

Comment: @ShivanRaptor is there any way in which we can set proper alignment from coding ? This is because it will create a problem when we set different different font from coding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom installed font not displayed correctly in UILabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414730/custom-installed-font-not-displayed-correctly-in-uilabel)

Comment: Also check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535498/uibutton-custom-font-vertical-alignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There may be two options for this:** 
1) One you can override drawText Method

```
- (void) drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{   
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {0,5,0,5};

    [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
}
```

2)You can use `sizeToFit` method to get exact height and width of UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

The correct values of `NSTextAlignment` are :

```
typedef enum _NSTextAlignment {
   NSLeftTextAlignment      = 0,
   NSRightTextAlignment     = 1,
   NSCenterTextAlignment    = 2,
   NSJustifiedTextAlignment = 3,
   NSNaturalTextAlignment   = 4
} NSTextAlignment;
```

`NSTextAlignmentCenter` is not a valid value.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSTextAlignment