# NSString sizing does not account for Greek breathing marks

Tags: ios, unicode, nsstring, wkinterfacelabel

I've got an app that displays Greek text. I use the [Cardo](http://scholarsfonts.net/cardofnt.html) font for good display. In working on an AppleWatch extension and app, it was pointed out to me that some of the special characters are being cut off.  This is how some example text should look (screenshot from an iPhone simulator):

[image: Good Greek display on phone]

Here is the same text on the Watch simulator:

[image: Bad Greek display on watch]

Note that the fancy accent character (to be specific, a breathing mark with a circumflex accent) on the second character of the first word is cut off. I tried setting the label's frame on the phone using some `NSString` measuring code like this:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cardo" size:16];
[self.view addSubview:label];
label.text = @"οὗτος ἦλθεν εἰς μαρτυρίαν ἵνα μαρτυρήσῃ περὶ τοῦ φωτός, ἵνα πάντες πιστεύσωσιν δι᾽ αὐτοῦ.";
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init];
style.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

CGRect rect = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:self.view.bounds.size
  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
  attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: label.font,
     NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style} context:nil];
label.frame = CGRectMake(5, 100, ceilf(rect.size.width), ceilf(rect.size.height));
label.layer.borderWidth = 1; //for clarity
label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

The result looks like this (the border is drawn for clarity's sake):

[image: Bad Greek display on phone]

Interestingly, if I use the system font instead of Cardo, the extra symbols display correctly:

[image: Greek in Helvetica works, but is ugly]

So, **my question**: What causes the `NSString` sizing to cut off the extra marks? Is there some option I can pass to the sizing method to correct this? Or better yet, is there some option I can set on the `WKInterfaceLabel` in the Watch app to get it to render correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is in the font itself, with the ascenders being set too tightly for proper display.

I would first try setting the UILabel's text inset by making a subclass of UILabel and overriding drawTextInRect:

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIEdgeInsets insets = {5, 0, 0, 0};
[super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
}
```

If you have tried increasing the text inset to accommodate the font and it has not worked, take a look at [Custom installed font not displayed correctly in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414730/custom-installed-font-not-displayed-correctly-in-uilabel/)

Comment: I increased the ascender from 1800 to 2000 and it seems to work great.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will fix it or not, but this will give you more to look into.  I ran into an issue with a font using "Lower Case" numbers, which is a typography style for tabular numbers.  I was able to create a variation of the font using a UIFontDescription that forced all numbers to be upper case.  In your case the font's ascenders go over the top of the font's capHeight.  There are a bunch of options for creating a font using a font descriptor and one of them may help.  Here is how I created the upper case number font.

```
_font = [UIFont fontWithName:_fontName size:size];

NSArray* featureSettings = @[
            @{
                 UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: @(kNumberCaseType),
                 UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: @(kUpperCaseNumbersSelector)
            }];


UIFontDescriptor* originalDescriptor = [_font fontDescriptor];
UIFontDescriptor* newDescriptor = [originalDescriptor fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes: @{UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute: featureSettings }];
_font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor: newDescriptor size: size];
```

Specifically check out the kVerticalPositionType.

I actually ran into a case in my iOS app where the font ascenders where going over the capHeight from the baseline up and my attributed string was getting cut off.  Since I was in quartz drawing code I just use the difference of the font's lineHeight with its ascender and padded the top.  Unfortunately that is not an option on the Apple Watch.