# How to leave a space between lines in UILabel?

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel

I am using `UILabel` into one of my application and its having multiple lines into it. Now I have to put **some more space between two lines** in `UILabel`. I tried to search out the solution, but not able to find it. How can I put more spacing between two lines?

Comment: What did u try..show some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `UILabel's Attribute Inspector`, change the text from `Plain` to `Attribute`, then change number of lines and line spacing, its not the `UILabel` thing but the string itself

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set it in the UILabel's Attribute Inspector.

Change Text type from `Plain` to `Attribute`, then change number of lines and line spacing.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

- You may find useful [link](http://mbauman.net/geek/2009/03/15/minor-truetype-font-editing-on-a-mac/) for spacing between two lines in `UILabel`.
- There are also third party libraries to do so.

  - Few examples are like

    1. [MSLabel](https://github.com/LemonCake/MSLabel)
    2. [MTLabel](https://github.com/srgtuszy/MTLabel)
- You can also add spacing directly in your fonts. To get more info,check this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414730/custom-installed-font-not-displayed-correctly-in-uilabel/19553827#19553827)