# How to Increase Line spacing in UILabel in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, line-spacing

I have a label which has few lines of text and I want to increase the spacing between the lines. There are similar questions asked by others but the solutions don't solve my problems. Also my label may or may not contain paragraphs. I am new to `Swift`. Is there a solution using storyboard? Or only through `NSAttributedString` its possible?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Programatically add LineSpacing to your `UILabel` using following snippet.

**Earlier Swift version**

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your text")

// *** Create instance of `NSMutableParagraphStyle`
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

// *** set LineSpacing property in points ***
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 2 // Whatever line spacing you want in points

// *** Apply attribute to string ***
attributedString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

// *** Set Attributed String to your label ***
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

**Swift 4.0**

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your text")

// *** Create instance of `NSMutableParagraphStyle`
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

// *** set LineSpacing property in points ***
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 2 // Whatever line spacing you want in points

// *** Apply attribute to string ***
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

// *** Set Attributed String to your label ***
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Your text")

// *** Create instance of `NSMutableParagraphStyle`
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

// *** set LineSpacing property in points ***
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 2 // Whatever line spacing you want in points

// *** Apply attribute to string ***
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

// *** Set Attributed String to your label ***
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: This shows an error "Value of type 'NSAttributedString' has no member 'addAttribute'  ".

Comment: We need to use `NSMutableAttributedString` instead `NSAttributedString`. I have updated asnwer.

Comment: Work with custom Fonts Also Great @

Dipen Panchasara

Comment: I don't know why but, as for me, this is only working if you set linespacing >= 1, I tried to set 0.5 / 0.75, it has no effect

Comment: No need for `NSMutableAttributedString`. Can use `NSAttributedString(string: "Your text", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : paragraphStyle])`

Comment: lineSpacing doesn't work with 0.5, 0.75 values. You should use -1, -2, -3 etc.

Answer (score 126):

**From Interface Builder:**

[image]

**Programmatically:**

**SWift 4 & 4.2**

Using label extension

```
extension UILabel {

    func setLineSpacing(lineSpacing: CGFloat = 0.0, lineHeightMultiple: CGFloat = 0.0) {

        guard let labelText = self.text else { return }

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
        paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeightMultiple

        let attributedString:NSMutableAttributedString
        if let labelattributedText = self.attributedText {
            attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: labelattributedText)
        } else {
            attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: labelText)
        }

        // (Swift 4.2 and above) Line spacing attribute
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))


        // (Swift 4.1 and 4.0) Line spacing attribute
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

        self.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```

Now call extension function

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "Set\nUILabel\nline\nspacing"

// Pass value for any one argument - lineSpacing or lineHeightMultiple
label.setLineSpacing(lineSpacing: 2.0) .  // try values 1.0 to 5.0

// or try lineHeightMultiple
//label.setLineSpacing(lineHeightMultiple = 2.0) // try values 0.5 to 2.0
```

Or using label instance (Just copy & execute this code to see result)

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "Set\nUILabel\nline\nspacing"
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
var style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 24 // change line spacing between paragraph like 36 or 48
style.minimumLineHeight = 20 // change line spacing between each line like 30 or 40

// Line spacing attribute
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringValue.characters.count))

// Character spacing attribute
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

label.attributedText = attrString
```

**Swift 3**

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "Set\nUILabel\nline\nspacing"
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
var style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 24 // change line spacing between paragraph like 36 or 48
style.minimumLineHeight = 20 // change line spacing between each line like 30 or 40
attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringValue.characters.count))
label.attributedText = attrString
```

Comment: "NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle" had error, I used "NSParagraphStyleAttributeName" instead.

Comment: @Alfi - It's difference of Swift language version. Your project's swift lang. version may be swift 3.x and here are answers for both versions. Try with Swift 3 code.

Comment: Hii @krunal, I have set Linespacing and LineHeight in Interface and I set text in UILabel Programmatically but it not working. if I add text in Interface then it work. can you please help me for this Thank You and I also set attributedText and text in UILabel but that approach is not working for me.

Comment: interface builder solution is only for static text. when we add attributed string in code , those attribute which is added from interface builder is not applied.

Comment: Works for me. But be aware that it resets any NSTextAlignment previously applied to label.

Answer (score 76):

You can control the line spacing in `storyboard`.

[image]

[Same question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494498/how-to-control-the-line-spacing-in-uilabel)

Comment: I actually tried this. But its not working. Also this is not useful for custom fonts.

Comment: If you are facing mis-alignment in custom fonts, try to update the `ascender` property as [mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8314285/988169).

Comment: Its not mis-alignment problem. I cannot select my custom font with the solution you said@pkc456

Comment: Its not mis-alignment problem. I couldnt select my custom font.But now I solved that by adding my Font through settings seperately in Attributed. But still spacing remains the same.@pkc456

Comment: I am able to update line spacing. Check video [here](http://sendvid.com/hwdu7udy).

Comment: This is for static text only. Try adding text programatticaly. This won't work.

Comment: This solution doesn't work when you add text programmatically

Answer (score 21):

Recent solution for Swift 5.0

```
private extension UILabel {

    // MARK: - spacingValue is spacing that you need
    func addInterlineSpacing(spacingValue: CGFloat = 2) {

        // MARK: - Check if there's any text
        guard let textString = text else { return }

        // MARK: - Create "NSMutableAttributedString" with your text
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textString)

        // MARK: - Create instance of "NSMutableParagraphStyle"
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

        // MARK: - Actually adding spacing we need to ParagraphStyle
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = spacingValue

        // MARK: - Adding ParagraphStyle to your attributed String
        attributedString.addAttribute(
            .paragraphStyle,
            value: paragraphStyle,
            range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length
        ))

        // MARK: - Assign string that you've modified to current attributed Text
        attributedText = attributedString
    }

}
```

And the usage:

```
let yourLabel = UILabel()
let yourText = "Hello \n world \n !"
yourLabel.text = yourText
yourLabel.addInterlineSpacing(spacingValue: 1.5)
```

Comment: This of course will only work if you're using `UILabel.text` and not `UILabel.attributedText`

Comment: Working for me.

Answer (score 16):

**Swift 4 and Swift 5**

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    func withLineSpacing(_ spacing: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = spacing
        attributedString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle,
                                      value: paragraphStyle,
                                      range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.count))
        return NSAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)
    }
}
```

**How to use**

```
    let example = NSAttributedString(string: "This is Line 1 \nLine 2 \nLine 3 ").withLineSpacing(15)
    testLabel.attributedText = example
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 11):

You can use this reusable extension:

```
extension String {

func lineSpaced(_ spacing: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = spacing
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: self, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle])
    return attributedString
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Dipen's answer updated for Swift 4

```
let attr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: today)
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 2
attr.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attr.length))
label.attributedText = attr;
```

Comment: This is no way Swift 4.

Answer (score 3):

```
extension UILabel {
    var spacing: CGFloat {
        get {return 0}
        set {
            let textAlignment = self.textAlignment
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = newValue
            let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: self.text ?? "", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle])
            self.attributedText = attributedString
            self.textAlignment = textAlignment
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "test"
label.spacing = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Swift 4:
    func set(text:String,
                         inLabel:UILabel,
                         withLineSpacing:CGFloat,
                         alignment:NSTextAlignment){
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = withLineSpacing
            let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
            attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle,
                                    value:paragraphStyle,
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
            inLabel.attributedText = attrString
            inLabel.textAlignment = alignment
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Create LabelStyle**

```
struct LabelStyle {
    
        let font: UIFont
        let fontMetrics: UIFontMetrics?
        let lineHeight: CGFloat?
        let tracking: CGFloat
        
        init(font: UIFont, fontMetrics: UIFontMetrics? = nil, lineHeight: CGFloat? = nil, tracking: CGFloat = 0) {
            self.font = font
            self.fontMetrics = fontMetrics
            self.lineHeight = lineHeight
            self.tracking = tracking
        }
        
        func attributes(for alignment: NSTextAlignment, lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakMode) -> [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] {
            
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.alignment = alignment
            paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
            
            var baselineOffset: CGFloat = .zero
            
            if let lineHeight = lineHeight {
                let lineHeightMultiple = lineHeight / font.lineHeight
                paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeightMultiple
                
                baselineOffset = 1 / lineHeightMultiple
                
                let scaledLineHeight: CGFloat = fontMetrics?.scaledValue(for: lineHeight) ?? lineHeight
                paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = scaledLineHeight
                paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = scaledLineHeight
            }
            
            return [
                NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
                NSAttributedString.Key.kern: tracking,
                NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset: baselineOffset,
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: font
            ]
        }
    }
```

**Create custom Label class and use our style**

```
public class Label: UILabel {
  
  var style: LabelStyle? { nil }
  
  public override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    
    if previousTraitCollection?.preferredContentSizeCategory != traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory {
      updateText()
    }
  }
  
  convenience init(text: String?, textColor: UIColor) {
    self.init()
    self.text = text
    self.textColor = textColor
  }
  
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
  }
  
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
    updateText()
  }
  
  private func commonInit() {
    font = style?.font
    adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
  }
  
  private func updateText() {
    text = super.text
  }
  
  public override var text: String? {
    get {
      guard style?.attributes != nil else {
        return super.text
      }
      
      return attributedText?.string
    }
    set {
      guard let style = style else {
        super.text = newValue
        return
      }
      
      guard let newText = newValue else {
        attributedText = nil
        super.text = nil
        return
      }
      
      let attributes = style.attributes(for: textAlignment, lineBreakMode: lineBreakMode)
      attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: newText, attributes: attributes)
    }
  }
}
```

**Create concrete Label**

```
public final class TitleLabel {

    override var style: LabelStyle? {
        LabelStyle(
            font: UIFont.Title(),
            lineHeight: 26.21,
            tracking: 0.14
        )
    }
}
```

**and use it**

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: TitleLabel!
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using attributed strings & paragraph styles, for small adjustemnts, font descriptors can also come in handy.

For instance:

```swift
let font: UIFont = .init(
    descriptor: UIFontDescriptor
        .preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: .body)
        .withSymbolicTraits(.traitLooseLeading)!,
    size: 0
)
```

This will create a font with a looser leading, resulting in a text with a slightly larger line height (it adds 2 points) than the default system font. `traitTightLeading` can also be used for the opposite effect (it reduces the leading of the font by 2 points).

I wrote a blog post comparing the approaches here: https://bootstragram.com/blog/line-height-with-uikit/.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for swift 5
this is reference to answer of https://stackoverflow.com/a/62116213/13171606

I Made some changes for "**NSMutableAttributedString**" and included the full example, i think it will help u all

**Note:** Please Adjust Color and Font style if found any error.

**Extension**

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    func withLineSpacing(_ spacing: CGFloat) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = spacing
            attributedString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle,
                                  value: paragraphStyle,
                                  range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.count))
            return NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedString)
    }
}
```

**Implementation Example**

```
let myAttributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Please enter the required details to change your AAAAAAAAA AAAAA AAAAA. Maximum AAAAA can be AAA AA AAA AA.\n\nNote: If you do not have a AAAAA AAAA then please AAAAAAA us at 111-111-111 or send us an email AAAA AAAA AAA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAA address at xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.", attributes: [
        .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14),
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.gray,
        .kern: 0.0]).withLineSpacing(8)
    myAttributedText.addAttributes([
        .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14),
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue],
                                   range: NSRange(location: 174, length: 11))
    myAttributedText.addAttributes([
        .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14),
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue],
                                   range: NSRange(location: 248, length: 28))
```

**UILable**

```
let myLabel: UILabel = {
   let label = UILabel()
   label.textAlignment = .left
   label.numberOfLines = 0
   label.attributedText = myAttributedText //Here is your Attributed String
   return label
}()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@discardableResult
func lineHeight(_ lineHeightMultiple: CGFloat) -> Self {
    guard let labelText = text else { return self}
    
    let fontHeight = font.lineHeight
    
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = fontHeight * (lineHeightMultiple - 1)
    
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: labelText)
    attributedString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
    
    attributedText = attributedString
    
    return self
}
```