# How to Increase Line spacing in UILabel in Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel, nsparagraphstyle, line-spacing

I want to increase the Line Spacing in UILabel but I can't figure it out how.

I found this solution [https://stackoverflow.com/a/39158698/8633963] on Stackoverflow but my Xcode always displays this:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'NSParagraphStyleAttributeName'
```

I think the answer is right but it did not work for me.
Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: The answer is there in mentioned SO link. Did you look at others' answer?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39158698/8633963 Opinion. Instead of defining programmatically, better to do the same from Interface builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 4 in this case you have to use `NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle` instead of `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName`

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 5**

```swift
import UIKit

extension UILabel {
    
    func setLineHeight(lineHeight: CGFloat) {
        guard let text = self.text else { return }
        
        let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        
        style.lineSpacing = lineHeight
        attributeString.addAttribute(
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle,
            value: style,
            range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
        
        self.attributedText = attributeString
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
import UIKit

    extension UILabel {

        func setLineHeight(lineHeight: CGFloat) {
            let text = self.text
            if let text = text {
                let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
                let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

                style.lineSpacing = lineHeight
                attributeString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: style, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(text)))
                self.attributedText = attributeString
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out this ridiculously simple solution that works!

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CommentTVCCell

    // Configure the cell...


    cell.myLabel?.text = "\n[\(indexPath.row + 1)]\n\n" + itemArray[indexPath.row].name

    //

    return cell 
}
```

//Notice the use of the  \n to load a return or as many as you wish. Make sure they are within a string designation.

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb to say OP didn't want a solution using a TableView