# How to control the line spacing in UILabel

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, uilabel, line-spacing

Is it possible to reduce the gap between text, when put in multiple lines in a `UILabel`? We can set the frame, font size and number of lines. I want to reduce the gap between the two lines in that label.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increase a space between two lines in multiline label?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880526/how-to-increase-a-space-between-two-lines-in-multiline-label)

Comment: May I suggest that you accept one of the answers that is correct for iOS 6.0 and later? The currently accepted answer is out of date.

Comment: For each line use a new `UILabel`, then embed all labels in a `StackView`. Finally adjust the `spacing` of `StackView`. Remember to stack them vertically.

Comment: Refer the following link for solution in Swift 2.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39158698/6602495

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44325650/342794 for storyboard tweak and other details.

Answer (score 284, accepted):

I thought about adding something new to this answer, so I don't feel as bad... Here is a **Swift** answer:

```
import Cocoa

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 40

let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Swift Answer")
attrString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

var tableViewCell = NSTableCellView()
tableViewCell.textField.attributedStringValue = attrString
```

---

<strike>"Short answer: you can't. To change the spacing between lines of text, you will have to subclass UILabel and roll your own drawTextInRect, or create multiple labels."</strike>

See: [Set UILabel line spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880526/how-to-increase-a-space-between-two-lines-in-multiline-label)

---

This is a really old answer, and other have already addded the new and better way to handle this.. Please see the up to date answers provided below.

Comment: Since iOS 6.0, you can control it via `NSAttributedString` (also available in properties of UILable in Xcode's interface builder).

Comment: Interestingly, as near as I can tell, you can add extra spacing between the lines, but not reduce it via the `NSParagraphStyle` when using an `NSAttributedString`. (I may need to do more testing of the other modifyable properties, but the `lineSpacing` property only allows you to increase it.)

Comment: see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19258637/832111) to see a way using NSAttributedString

Comment: @livingtech That is infuriating, and I believe you are correct. Have you found any workarounds?

Comment: Here's what I did and it works great. This is using TTTAttributedLabel, but it should work for and AttributedString:

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 1;
    [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:whole];

Comment: Using iOS 8.2 I was able to to reduce it. You can't set it to 0, however.

Comment: Just to clarify something in this thread.  If you want to shrink the line spacing set the line height to 1.0, and then setLineHeightMultiple to a lower value < 1.0, like: [paragraphStyle setLineHeightMultiple:0.8] or paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 0.8

Comment: **1)** why are mentioning `tableViewCell` is there any discussion about a tableView or a cell? **2)** when we are changing the layout, why don't we need to call 'setNeedsDisplay' again?

Comment: @Honey A UI element is required to see the feature in action. Any will do. Other answers use `UILabel`, I used `NSTextField` within a `NSTableCellView`. Layout and drawing are separate things. `setNeedsDisplay` is for drawing and rendering updates.

Comment: what worked for me is this. extension UILabel {
    func setLineHeight(lineHeight: CGFloat)  {
        let text = self.text
        if let text = text
        {
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
            let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            style.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeight
            attributedString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count))
            self.attributedText = attributedString
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 430):

In Xcode 6 you can do this in the storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Take more advantages of storyboard!

Comment: This is *exactly* what I needed (I needed to compress the lines). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Using this option seems to break my ib every time, does anyone know what the issue could be there?

Comment: @PaperThick have the same issue in 6.1.1. It "harlem shake" for few minutes. Doesn't know how to fix it :) [Xcode Shaking](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ln1phh80ka9jfcc/xcode_label_attributes_bug.gif?dl=0)

Comment: Is there a way to set custom fonts this way ? I can't seem to change that helvetica neue to any other font.

Comment: This is a great solution. Unfortunately Xcode continues to disappoint . . . freezes every time I open this box

Comment: @Anconia Indeed, an unworkable solution. I've found that switching back to a plain text label will *crash* Xcode 6.3.2. I had to delete the label and start again.

Comment: Xcode 6.3.1 when it Harlem Shakes it looks like its broken, but if you click elsewhere eventually it'll go away and all seems ok.

Comment: If you enable 'Attributed', and then open the file as source code you can edit the 'lineHeightMultiple' manually, and therefore bypass the Harlem Shake bug

Comment: @Marcos it is only working in system font, there is a radar about it for several versions, at this stage customer fonts only work via the CODe and not from the interface builder.

Comment: The shake bug is still there in Xcode 7.1.1. Careful what you do while it's shaking, Xcode will queue your clicks and keypresses and fire them all at once after it stops. I ended up having multiple source files modified and moved around. Edit the value directly in the storyboard XML to be safe until this absurd bug is fixed.

Comment: Storyboard and I don't get along, but this is great. +1000

Comment: @azdev for anyone still looking at this, I'm on longer getting the shakes in Xcode 7.3, but I think this is the first version where it hasn't been a problem

Comment: @MarcosCurvello My solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38643488/5175709) is a workaround that may be useful.

Answer (score 109):

Starting from iOS 6 you can set an attributed string to the UILabel. Check the following :

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:label.text];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = spacing;
[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, label.text.length)];

label.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: The `attributedString` must be an `NSMutableAttributedString` (NOT NSAttributedString)

Comment: The first line code should be `NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"sample text"];`

Comment: The `lineSpacing` property of the `NSMutableParagraphStyle` is never negative, so the line height cannot be reduced with this approach. To answer the question, you have to use another property, see @d.ennis answer.

Answer (score 84):

The solutions stated here didn't work for me. I found a slightly different way to do it with the iOS 6 NSAttributeString:

```
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0; 
NSString* string = @"String with line one. \n Line two. \n Line three.";
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style  = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
style.minimumLineHeight = 30.f;
style.maximumLineHeight = 30.f;
NSDictionary *attributtes = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style,};
myLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string
                                                         attributes:attributtes];   
[myLabel sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Line height is font size dependent.  Line spacing is just that, line spacing.  You may get things to work out by just setting min/max line height, but that's only because the current font sizes you're using aren't greater than the line height boundaries.  Per the documentation: "... glyphs and graphics exceeding this height will overlap neighboring lines ... Although this limit applies to the line itself, line spacing adds extra space between adjacent lines."

Comment: +1, If you want to reduce the spacing between lines, this is what you want to do. The real line spacing is most likely 0 by default, this is why people report you can only increase it. The problem with spacing being too big comes from the line height being too big, this is why this will get the job done 99% of the time.

Comment: This is the only answer I could find that uses the actual line height value (instead of a ratio) common to design applications such as Photoshop, Sketch, CSS, etc.

Answer (score 43):

**From Interface Builder (Storyboard/XIB):**

[image]

**Programmatically:**

**SWift 4**

Using label extension

```
extension UILabel {

    // Pass value for any one of both parameters and see result
    func setLineSpacing(lineSpacing: CGFloat = 0.0, lineHeightMultiple: CGFloat = 0.0) {

        guard let labelText = self.text else { return }

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
        paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeightMultiple

        let attributedString:NSMutableAttributedString
        if let labelattributedText = self.attributedText {
            attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: labelattributedText)
        } else {
            attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: labelText)
        }

        // Line spacing attribute
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

        self.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```

Now call extension function

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "How to\ncontrol\nthe\nline spacing\nin UILabel"

// Pass value for any one argument - lineSpacing or lineHeightMultiple
label.setLineSpacing(lineSpacing: 2.0) .  // try values 1.0 to 5.0

// or try lineHeightMultiple
//label.setLineSpacing(lineHeightMultiple = 2.0) // try values 0.5 to 2.0
```

Or using label instance (Just copy & execute this code to see result)

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "How to\ncontrol\nthe\nline spacing\nin UILabel"
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
var style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 24 // change line spacing between paragraph like 36 or 48
style.minimumLineHeight = 20 // change line spacing between each line like 30 or 40

// Line spacing attribute
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringValue.characters.count))

// Character spacing attribute
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

label.attributedText = attrString
```

**Swift 3**

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "How to\ncontrol\nthe\nline spacing\nin UILabel"
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
var style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 24 // change line spacing between paragraph like 36 or 48
style.minimumLineHeight = 20 // change line spacing between each line like 30 or 40
attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringValue.characters.count))
label.attributedText = attrString
```

Comment: Add  the line  " paragraphStyle.alignment = self.textAlignment" to keep the original alignment . Otherwise, the text will be left aligned.

Comment: For anyone loosing ellipsis on large texts, then use: paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail

Answer (score 40):

I've made this simple extension that works very well for me:

```
extension UILabel {
    func setLineHeight(lineHeight: CGFloat) {
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 1.0
        paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeight
        paragraphStyle.alignment = self.textAlignment

        let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        if (self.attributedText != nil) {
            attrString.append( self.attributedText!)
        } else {
            attrString.append( NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text!))
            attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: self.font, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
        }
        attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
        self.attributedText = attrString
    }
}
```

Copy this in a file, so then you can use it like this

```
myLabel.setLineHeight(0.7)
```

Comment: remember if you doing this while you are also using Storyboard for this label, then be sure to set your label's lines to 0

Comment: Why don't you just directly set the `lineSpacing` and forget about setting `lineHeightMultiple`?

Comment: Because the key to reduce the line height is 'lineHeightMultiple', no lineSpacing

Comment: say you want your line height to be 1.4, why can't you just write `.lineSpacing = 1.4` and forget all about `.lineHeightMultiple`...

Comment: Hah! I tried, and I didn't work, but I wonder why I don't see other answers here not using your mechanism, I mean they just directly set the lineSpacing. See the accepted answer...

Comment: This seems to push my uilabel downwards when i put it in a stackview- anyone have a working project?

Comment: You saved me friend :)

Comment: It works, but you have to make sure you've already assigned text to the label. Otherwise it will crash when your code tries to unwrap the text attribute

Answer (score 19):

There's an alternative answer now in iOS 6, which is to set attributedText on the label, using an NSAttributedString with the appropriate paragraph styles. See this stack overflow answer for details on line height with NSAttributedString:

[Core Text - NSAttributedString line height done right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138859/core-text-nsattributedstring-line-height-done-right)

Answer (score 16):

Here is a class that subclass UILabel to have line-height property : https://github.com/LemonCake/MSLabel

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I also tried to use MTLabel, but this one was better.

Comment: Does anyone know if MSLabel supports the '\n' character?

Answer (score 15):

In Swift and as a function, inspired by DarkDust

```
// Usage: setTextWithLineSpacing(myEpicUILabel,text:"Hello",lineSpacing:20)
func setTextWithLineSpacing(label:UILabel,text:String,lineSpacing:CGFloat)
{
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing

    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))

    label.attributedText = attrString
}
```

Answer (score 13):

According @Mike 's Answer, reducing the `lineHeightMultiple` is the key point. Example below, it work well for me:

```
NSString* text = label.text;
CGFloat textWidth = [text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: label.font}].width;
if (textWidth > label.frame.size.width) {
  NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
  paragraph.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
  paragraph.lineSpacing = 1.0f;
  paragraph.lineHeightMultiple = 0.75;     // Reduce this value !!!
  NSMutableAttributedString* attrText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
  [attrText addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraph range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];
  label.attributedText = attrText;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**SWIFT 3** useful extension for set space between lines more easily :)

```
extension UILabel
{
    func setLineHeight(lineHeight: CGFloat)
    {
        let text = self.text
        if let text = text 
        {

            let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
            let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()

           style.lineSpacing = lineHeight
           attributeString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                        value: style,
                                        range: NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count))

           self.attributedText = attributeString
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've found a way where you can set the **real line height** (not a factor) and it even renders **live in Interface Builder**. Just follow the instructions below. Code is written in **Swift 4**.

---

**Step #1:** Create a file named `DesignableLabel.swift` and insert the following code:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class DesignableLabel: UILabel {
    @IBInspectable var lineHeight: CGFloat = 20 {
        didSet {
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = lineHeight
            paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = lineHeight
            paragraphStyle.alignment = self.textAlignment

            let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text!)
            attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: font, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrString.length))
            attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrString.length))
            attributedText = attrString
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Step #2:** Place a `UILabel` into a Storyboard/XIB and set its class to `DesignableLabel`. Wait for your project to build (build must succeed!).

[image: Specifying the class to your UILabel]

---

**Step 3:** Now you should see a new property in the properties pane named "Line Height". Just set the value you like and you should **see the results immediately!**

[image: Set Line Height in properties]

Comment: You don't need a subclass to do this. You can do it in a UILabel Extension and still add @IBInspectable - which is important if you already have a UILabel subclass and you don't want a weird class hierarchy

Answer (score 3):

Here is a subclass of UILabel that sets `lineHeightMultiple` and makes sure the intrinsic height is large enough to not cut off text.

```
@IBDesignable
class Label: UILabel {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var size = super.intrinsicContentSize
        let padding = (1.0 - lineHeightMultiple) * font.pointSize
        size.height += padding
        return size
    }

    override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            updateAttributedText()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var lineHeightMultiple: CGFloat = 1.0 {
        didSet {
            updateAttributedText()
        }
    }

    private func updateAttributedText() {
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeightMultiple
        attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text ?? "", attributes: [
            .font: font,
            .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
            .foregroundColor: textColor
        ])
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}
```

Comment: extra padding must be (lineHeightMultiple - 1.0) * font.pointSize, right?

Comment: The code above as-is seemed to work for me. But maybe you are right. Did you try your change? @PavelAlexeev

Comment: No, I stick with lineSpacing instead of lineHeightMultiple :)

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 extension:

```
import UIKit
    
extension UILabel {
  func setTextWithLineSpacing(text: String, lineHeightMultiply: CGFloat = 1.3) {
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeightMultiply
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
    self.attributedText = attributedString
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution works for me i just change   `paragraphStyle.alignment = .center`  to `paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        paragraphStyle.baseWritingDirection = NSParagraphStyle.defaultWritingDirection(forLanguage: GeneralMethods.getSelectedLanguage().stringValue)` and its automatically adopt direction according to selected language.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 2.0...

Add an extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func attributesWithLineHeight(font: String, color: UIColor, fontSize: CGFloat, kern: Double, lineHeightMultiple: CGFloat) -> [String: NSObject] {
        let titleParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        titleParagraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeightMultiple

        let attribute = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color,
            NSKernAttributeName: kern,
            NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: font, size: fontSize)!,
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: titleParagraphStyle
        ]
        return attribute
    }
}
```

Now, just set your UILabel as attributedText:

```
self.label.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "SwiftExample", attributes: attributesWithLineHeight("SourceSans-Regular", color: UIColor.whiteColor(), fontSize: 20, kern: 2.0, lineHeightMultiple: 0.5))
```

Obviously, I added a bunch of parameters that you may not need. Play around -- feel free to rewrite the method -- I was looking for this on a bunch of different answers so figured I'd post the whole extension in case it helps someone out there...  -rab

Answer (score 1):

Swift3 - In a UITextView or UILabel extension, add this function:

I added some code to keep the current attributed text if you are already using attributed strings with the view (instead of overwriting them).

```
func setLineHeight(_ lineHeight: CGFloat) {
    guard let text = self.text, let font = self.font else { return }

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 1.0
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeight
    paragraphStyle.alignment = self.textAlignment

    var attrString:NSMutableAttributedString
    if let attributed = self.attributedText {
        attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributed)
    } else {
        attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        attrString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
    }
    attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
    self.attributedText = attrString
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer... If you're passing the string programmatically, you need to pass a attributed string instead a regular string and change it's style.(iOS10)

```
NSMutableAttributedString * attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your \nregular \nstring"];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[style setLineSpacing:4];
[attrString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                   value:style
                   range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length)];
_label.attributedText = attrString;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help with it. You can then assign your label to this custom class within the storyboard and use it's parameters directly within the properties:

```
open class SpacingLabel : UILabel {

    @IBInspectable open var lineHeight:CGFloat = 1 {
        didSet {
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 1.0
            paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = self.lineHeight
            paragraphStyle.alignment = self.textAlignment

            let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text!)
            attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: self.font, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
            attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
            self.attributedText = attrString
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: This should help with it. You can then assign your label to this custom class within the storyboard and use it's parameters directly within the properties.

Comment: please don't put content related to your answer in the comments. your answer should be helpful without having to read through the comments

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4 label extension. Creating NSMutableAttributedString before passing into function in case there are extra attributes required for the attributed text.

```
extension UILabel {

    func setLineHeightMultiple(to height: CGFloat, withAttributedText attributedText: NSMutableAttributedString) {

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 1.0
        paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = height
        paragraphStyle.alignment = textAlignment

        attributedText.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.length - 1))

        self.attributedText = attributedText
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me (ios 7 & ios 8  for sure).

```
_label.numberOfLines=2;
_label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple=0.5;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 1.0;

NSDictionary *nameAttributes=@{
                               NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
                               NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:@2.0
                               };


NSAttributedString *string=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"22m\nago" attributes:nameAttributes];
_label.attributedText=string;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution in swift. The subclass should work for both attributedText and text property and for characterSpacing + lineSpacing. It retains the spacing if a new string or attributedString is set.

```
open class UHBCustomLabel : UILabel {
    @IBInspectable open var characterSpacing:CGFloat = 1 {
        didSet {
            updateWithSpacing()
        }

    }
    @IBInspectable open var lines_spacing:CGFloat = -1 {
        didSet {
            updateWithSpacing()
        }

    }
    open override var text: String? {
        set {
            super.text = newValue
            updateWithSpacing()
        }
        get {
            return super.text
        }
    }
    open override var attributedText: NSAttributedString? {
        set {
            super.attributedText = newValue
            updateWithSpacing() 
        }
        get {
            return super.attributedText
        }
    }
    func updateWithSpacing() {
        let attributedString = self.attributedText == nil ? NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text ?? "") : NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText!)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: self.characterSpacing, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
        if lines_spacing >= 0 {
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lines_spacing
            paragraphStyle.alignment = textAlignment
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
        }
        super.attributedText = attributedString
    }
}
```