# How to reduce a space between two lines in multiline UILabel in iphone

Tags: iphone, uilabel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to control the line spacing in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494498/how-to-control-the-line-spacing-in-uilabel)

I want to reduce a space between two lines in multiline `UILabel` in iPhone, how I can achieve this, It is very critical thing I want solution for that, Please give me idea.

Comment: can u provide screenshot for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not as there is no spacing parameter in UILabel. Instead, You should see these third party libraries for your purpose.

[MSLabel](https://github.com/LemonCake/MSLabel)

[MTLabel](https://github.com/Tuszy/MTLabel)

Comment: Since iOS6 you can see [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19258637/832111) answer.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't**.

To change the spacing between lines of text, you will have to subclass`UILabel`

Check out the  [thirdparty CODE](https://github.com/Tuszy/MTLabel) to get into more detail and It supports almost every feature of `UILabel` .

Comment: check out the dupe link I have provided. it will be very helpful