# How Overriding method drawTextInRect change line space

Tags: uilabel, overriding, line, space

How should I override to change the spacing between lines in UILabel? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next thread discusses alternatives to manage UILabel line spacing.-

[How to control the line spacing in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494498/how-to-control-the-line-spacing-in-uilabel)