# Multiline UILabel height increases even when the text is one line long

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am using a `UILabel` within a `tableViewCell`. Some of the cells have texts that are one line, and some 2 lines. I have set the trailing space, leading space and top space from superview constraints to the label. Following are the settings:

- lines = 0
- Line Breaks: Word Wrap  (tried other options as well)

If the text crosses a particular length, for some reason, the label height seems to have increased to accommodate 2 lines, though the text is only one line. As show below (background is red for reference):
[image]

For example, In the first row, the actual text is one line, but the height is increased when compared to the other rows.

Is there any reason why it might be happening so? I am not setting the height anywhere from the code.

**EDIT**

Also, I have set a custom font for UILabel throughout out the App using the following:

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:myFont];
```

I am not sure if that should cause any issue..

Also, the screen shot of the constraints set are:

[image]

Comment: How do you define size constraints for your cells ?

Comment: it seems that bottom space constraint is also been set, if this is the case then jst remove this bottom space constraint, better if yo u share the constraint screeshot

Comment: @ZAZ.. no the bottom constraint is not set..

Comment: @Antzi: I have not set any size constraints for the cells.

Comment: Your `UILabel` adapt to fill the space available (due to the absence of a label such as `Original food choice`.) You have to decide on non ambiguous rules to set the correct sizing in case one of the label is empty (maybe set a minimum size to both labels ?)

Comment: @Antzi.. the original food choice label is present too..

Comment: @Antzi.. For the same cell, if i increase the character count to beyond a certain point, label height increases..

Comment: @ShantiK Try setting a minimum height for the food choice label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know its weird, I did face the same issue before and it was because of the content hugging priorities which i set without much knowledge on it. I solved it by removing the label and adding it again.try that.

Answer (score 3):

Got the same issue.
After checking content hugging priorities got the same results.
Finally found that it was caused by **Label-Preferred Width** set to **Explicit** in **Metrics Tab**, in label configuration.

Unchecked and solved =)

Comment: Thanks, just wasted 3 hours of my life until I found your solution. I wasn't able to find the property in IB so I set it via code: `label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this issue with an `NSAttributedString`, but in conjunction with using the `lineSpacing` property of `NSMutableParagraphStyle`.  I'm using Auto Layout entirely programmatically and with `numberOfLines` set to `0`.  Multiline text was working fine until I wanted to add line spacing, at which time I encountered this issue.  Adjusting the content hugging and compression resistance didn't do anything for me, nor did using `UILabel`'s `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property (I'm not currently).

What fixed it was applying an `NSRange` to the exact amount of characters in my text string:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = spacing;
[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, label.text.length)];

label.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16057159/482557.