# UILabel Line Spacing

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uilabel

I am trying to set the line spacing in a `UILabel` as specified by Mike Slutsky [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494498/how-to-control-the-line-spacing-in-uilabel/19258637#19258637). It works correctly for the text I specify from the Storyboard. When I try to set the `UILabel.text` in code, it reverts back to the default line spacing. Can someone help me understand how to either:

1. Keep it from reverting to default, and use the settings I specified on the Storyboard or
2. Set the value in code.

I've seen a lot of examples around using `NSAttribute` and `NSParagraph`, but since it's now possible to set in the Storyboard, I would expect their may be a more straightforward answer. Many thanks for the help!

I set the "Height Multiple" as illustrated in the above link, and my only code is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        textView.text = "Some example text"
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

If I remove the textView.text line, it displays correctly, otherwise it's set back to the default line spacing (or Height Multiple).

Comment: Not a whole lot of code to show, but i've added it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Very helpful, actually! This gives me a much better idea what the issue is. I think I can answer based on that.

Comment: When you set `textView.text` that resets the attributed text.  Set `textView.attributedText` instead, and use an `NSAttributedString` every time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's what's going on. You set things up in the storyboard with custom line spacing. This means, even though you may not know it, that in the storyboard you have set the label's `attributedText`.

But if you then come along and set the label's `text` in code, as you are doing, you throw away the `attributedText` *and therefore all the attributes* that it had. That is why, as you rightly say, things revert to the default look of the label.

The solution is: instead of setting the label's `text`, set its `attributedText`. In particular, fetch the label's existing `attributedText`; assign it into an NSMutableAttributedString so you can change it; replace its string while keeping the attributes; and assign it back to the label's `attributedText`.

So for example (I have called my label `lab` - your `textView` is a bad choice, as a text view is whole different animal):

```
let text = self.lab.attributedText
let mas = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString:text)
mas.replaceCharactersInRange(NSMakeRange(0, count(mas.string.utf16)), 
    withString: "Little poltergeists make up the principle form of material manifestation")
self.lab.attributedText = mas
```

Comment: That makes total sense. Thanks for the reply and for the code! I'm getting  the error **utf16Count' is unavailable: Take the count of a UTF-16 view instead, i.e. count(str.utf16)**, but i'm researching a solution to that. Thanks again

Comment: You're right, I tested under an old version of Xcode. Sorry about that.

Comment: Fixed now, sorry about that.

Comment: I knew you'd like it. Notice that this simply imposes the attributes of the _first character_ of the old text onto the new text. This may work in your simple case, because the first character's attributes include the paragraph attributes and font attributes you are interested in; but if your attributes were more complicated, you'd need more complicated code.

Answer (score 1):

UILabel has

`@property(nonatomic, copy) NSAttributedString *attributedText` 
since iOS 6.0,

This property is nil by default. Assigning a new value to this property also replaces the value of the text property with the same string data, albeit without any formatting information. In addition, assigning a new a value updates the values in the font, textColor, and other style-related properties so that they reflect the style information starting at location 0 in the attributed string.

If you set `textView.text = "Some example text"` again, you will loose your attributes. You should only pick one of them and not switching between them if you are sure what you are doing

Answer (score 1):

Here is @matt 's answer in Obj. C:

```
  NSMutableAttributedString *mas = [self.lab.attributedText mutableCopy];
  [mas replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [mas.string length]) 
    withString:@"Little poltergeists make up the principle form of material manifestation"]; 
  self.lab.attributedText = mas;
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**
Just copy & execute this code to see result

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "UILabel\nLine\nSpacing"
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
var style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 24 // change line spacing between paragraph like 36 or 48
style.minimumLineHeight = 20 // change line spacing between each line like 30 or 40
attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringValue.characters.count))
label.attributedText = attrString
```