# changing line height of UILabel not working with auto line count Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I am assigning lines to 0 to make the lines count automatic with UILabel in a tablecellview

[image]

and I also want to increase the line height so it could look nicely

and I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494498/how-to-control-the-line-spacing-in-uilabel)

[image]

But it did not take effect and the result kept the same (no additional line height gained)
[image]

Comment: Do you need cell height based on label text content length?

Comment: Try to set this attribute [programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494498/how-to-control-the-line-spacing-in-uilabel/44325650#44325650)

Comment: @Krunal - but your comments is related to spacing

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Yea, exactly, that is shown here in second snapshot. line 'Height Multple' is set to 2, from storyboard layout, but the same is not effective. I just suggested to use code from there and try setting it programtically. May it would work...