# Line Spacing in xcode/swift Label and TextView

Tags: swift, xcode

My question is related to solving a problem and also to improve my understanding of swift.

I have a UILabel and a TextView.  I have the same size font in both.  However, in the TextView I am using attributed strings.  The fonts appear the same but the line spacing is greater in the label.  My problem is I cannot find a way to change the line spacing in the Label other than switching to Attributed String for the Label or for that matter even determining what the present spacing is.

Q1:  Is there no other way to control the label spacing other than Attributed Strings?

Q2:  Because of issues like this, should I be thinking that Attributed Strings might be a "best practice" regardless -- to give more control?

Comment: Q1: Exactly - you should use attributed strings if you want to fine-tune things like line spacing. Q2: No. If you don't need special formatting, use regular text, as it consumes less power. If you have lots of labels, a little goes a long way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control the line spacing in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494498/how-to-control-the-line-spacing-in-uilabel)

Comment: Thank you.  The comment about consuming less power helps me understand why to use the UILabel if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set linespacing in Label Attribute inspector.
See screenshot.[image]