# Line Spacing Using User Define Runtime Attributes

Tags: swift, uibutton, storyboard

**Is there any ways to adjust line spacing in user define runtime attributes?**

I wouldn't like to use title->attributed->line and that doesn't work for custom fonts when I don't install custom fonts in my machine.

[image: storyboard runtime attributes]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to control the line spacing in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494498/how-to-control-the-line-spacing-in-uilabel)

Comment: @jawadAli  No, those answer is not the way that I want. My question has " user define runtime attributes"

Comment: you can create them

Answer (score -1):

Oh - linespacing doesn't work with value 1, 2, 3. I have to use large value like 40