# Swift label not updating frame due change of font size

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

currently, I am creating a table view that contains an `imageView` as main UI item inside the cell and on top op that there is a label. Now I'm facing an issue where for long text, the frame of the label is not accurate, and for a long text it is taking a lot of space and it seems like there is a line break but there isn't, this is the issue:

[Label issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRxBm.png)

This are the properties of the label
[Label properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B15PY.png)

This is my `ViewController` and the constraints that I'm using
[View Controller on Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhO84.png)

Additional Details

1. For the Cell, I'm not adding extra code, I just have the `IBOutlets` and nothing more.
2. On the `CellForRowAtIndexPath`, I'm not doing additional code more than setting the image and setting the text.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running it on the actual device?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to control the line spacing in UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494498/how-to-control-the-line-spacing-in-uilabel)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Content hugging Priority of Label

Answer (score 0):

The font you've selected - Noto Nastaliq Urdu Bold - has very specific type layout properties.

Compare it with the default system font.

Using this code:

```
    let fontDefault = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0, weight: .bold)
    guard let fontNotoBld = UIFont(name: "NotoNastaliqUrdu-Bold", size: 17) else {
        fatalError("Could not create font!")
    }

    print("fontDefault.lineHeight:\t",fontDefault.lineHeight)
    print("fontNotoBld.lineHeight:\t",fontNotoBld.lineHeight)
    print()
    
    print("fontDefault.ascender:\t",fontDefault.ascender)
    print("fontNotoBld.ascender:\t",fontNotoBld.ascender)
    print()

    print("fontDefault.descender:\t",fontDefault.descender)
    print("fontNotoBld.descender:\t",fontNotoBld.descender)
    print()

    print("fontDefault.xHeight:\t",fontDefault.xHeight)
    print("fontNotoBld.xHeight:\t",fontNotoBld.xHeight)
    print()

    print("fontDefault.capHeight:\t",fontDefault.capHeight)
    print("fontNotoBld.capHeight:\t",fontNotoBld.capHeight)
    print()
```

we get this output in the debug console:

```
fontDefault.lineHeight:  20.287109375
fontNotoBld.lineHeight:  42.5

fontDefault.ascender:    16.1865234375
fontNotoBld.ascender:    32.368

fontDefault.descender:   -4.1005859375
fontNotoBld.descender:   -10.132000000000001

fontDefault.xHeight:     9.13916015625
fontNotoBld.xHeight:     9.112

fontDefault.capHeight:   11.97802734375
fontNotoBld.capHeight:   12.138000000000002
```

I don't know exactly why, but my assumption is that Noto Nastaliq Urdu supports many more language characters which often have very different shapes and heights.

You can either use a more standard font, or design your UI to accommodate the bigger spacing.

---

**Edit**

You could *try* using attributed text with line height settings. However, it will affect the top spacing of the text to a point that it may not suffice.

Here's an example with 3 labels:

- top label uses default settings
- second label changes maximumLineHeight to 17
- third label changes maximumLineHeight to 26

  ```
    let titleText = "Label with enough text to cause word wrapping onto multiple lines."

    guard let fontNotoBold = UIFont(name: "NotoNastaliqUrdu-Bold", size: 17) else {
        fatalError("Could not create font!")
    }

    // without paragraphStyle attribute
    var attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: titleText)
    attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: fontNotoBold, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
    label1.attributedText = attrString

    // with paragraphStyle max line height: 17
    let ps2 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    ps2.maximumLineHeight = 17
    attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: titleText)
    attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: fontNotoBold, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
    attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:ps2, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
    label2.attributedText = attrString

    // with paragraphStyle max line height: 26
    let ps3 = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    ps3.maximumLineHeight = 26
    attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: titleText)
    attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: fontNotoBold, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
    attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:ps3, range:NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
    label3.attributedText = attrString
  ```

Here's the result:

[image]

With a little more experimentation, such as adding a newline (`"\n"`) at the beginning, you might be able to get it to a satisfactory appearance.