# Set a NativeScript Label line height on iOS

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a label with a large font size, and the default line-height is quite loose for my taste.  I'd like to reduce it to less than the default.

Providing a `line-height` value larger than the `font-size` does increase the line spacing, but a smaller value (or negative value) does not reduce it to be smaller than the default on iOS.

From [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8120#issuecomment-558656028), I got this snippet that I updated to work with the latest NS;

```js
import { Label } from "@nativescript/core/ui/label";

export function setIOSLineHeight(label: Label, lineHeight: number){
    const iosLabel = label.nativeView;

    let attributedString;
    if (iosLabel.attributedText) {
        attributedString = iosLabel.attributedText;
    } else {
        attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.alloc().initWithString(iosLabel.text);
    }

    let range = new NSRange({ location: 0, length: iosLabel.text.length });
    const paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.alloc().init();
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 0;
    paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = lineHeight;
    paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = lineHeight;
    attributedString.addAttributeValueRange(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, paragraphStyle, range);
    iosLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
}
```

However, calling this method in the `mounted()` lifecycle method does not have any effect for any value of `lineHeight` - even ones that do have an effect via the CSS property:

```
<template>
    <Page ref="page">
        <Label ref="topLine" text="Hello this is a text that flows onto multiple lines" textWrap="true" />
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
import { isIOS } from 'tns-core-modules/platform';
import { setIOSLineHeight } from '../label-helper.ts';

export default {
    mounted() {
        if (isIOS) {
            /* Has no effect, regardless of value */
            setIOSLineHeight(this.$refs.topLine, 40);
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
Label {
    font-size: 60;
    /* Does work */
    line-height: 100;
    /* Does not work */
    line-height: 40;
}
</style>
```

How can I reduce the line height of my `Label` to a value smaller than the font size?

Answer (score 0):

In NativeScript I have used the following code to handle both IOS and Android for Line Spacing

```
function labelLineHeight(nsLabel) {

    if(isIOS){
        var label= nsLabel.ios;
        var attributedString;

        if(label.atributedText){
            attributedString = label.atributedText;
        }
        else{
            attributedString=NSMutableAttributedString.alloc().initWithString(label.text);
        }
        var paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.alloc().init();
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5;
        var range= NSMakeRange(0, label.text.length);
        attributedString.addAttributeValueRange(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, paragraphStyle, range);
        label.attributedText = attributedString;
    }
    if(isAndroid){
        var label = nsLabel.android;
        //Default spacing is 20% of text size
        //setLineSpacing(add,multiplyby);
        label.setLineSpacing(12, 1);
    }   
}
```

Also follow [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494498/how-to-control-the-line-spacing-in-uilabel) for more inputs on the line-spacing. You can see the [pull request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/4534) too for reference.

Comment: That seems to be largely the same code as what I have, and doesn't seem to have an effect on reducing the line-height from the default on iOS

Comment: After some additional poking around, it does seem like the `attributedString` is generated fine, but assigning it to `label.attributedText` does nothing; the label will still display the contents of `label.text` rather than `label.attributedText`