# xib control for line height in multiple line label/text view

Tags: text, label, xib, css

How do I edit the line height (as in the distance btwn the text lines in a multiple line Label or Text View) in the xib? 
I am looking for something in the xib toolset, but I am starting to believe that it can only be done by specifying it direct in the code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no parameter for adjusting the line height, but check out [Set UILabel line spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880526/how-to-increase-a-space-between-two-lines-in-multiline-label) which suggests to subclass `UILabel` or use a 3rd party library.