# How do I change the line spacing in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to change the spacing between lines in the Visual Studio 2012 code editing area? After having worked with IntelliJ IDEA for a while, I got accustomed to a slightly larger line spacing (1.2), and I want to achieve the same effect in VS12.
For comparison, the top one is IDEA with 12 pixels spacing between lines, the bottom one is VS12 with 10 pixels spacing:

[image]

I find the IDEA version much easier to read, even if it's just 2px difference. Does anyone know?

Comment: ⁺¹, though I wanted the contrary: decrease the space. For me a space of almost one line size is too big.

Comment: This is honestly a really useful question!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've found a workaround which works pretty well, partly alread described in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880526/how-to-increase-a-space-between-two-lines-in-multiline-label#comment18673753_10702956).
You need to download and install [TypeLight](http://cr8.netfirms.com/typelight.html) (free for personal use), and open the *Consolas.ttf* file inside. To adjust the line spacing, go to Font -> Metrics -> Advanced and change the "Line Gap" to your desire (I changed "Type Line Gap" as well, but I have no idea what this actually does). I experimented a bit with a values and found around 730 to be similar to the 12 pixels spacing in IDEA.

To distinguish the modified font from the regular Consolas, I suggest changing the name of the font under Font -> Names (to "Consolas Spaced" or something). Save the font, double-click the file and choose "Install" from the preview dialog. Then (re)start Visual Studio, choose your modified font and you're done.

Comment: As stated here [http://logotalks.com/2011/08/23/advanced-font-metrics-in-fontlab/](http://logotalks.com/2011/08/23/advanced-font-metrics-in-fontlab/), **Line Gap** “is used by the Mac OS to compensate Ascender and Descender values and calculate the correct distance between baselines of the text” and **Typo Line Gap** “is a distance between bottom line of the upper line of text and top line of the lowerline of text”

Comment: +1. Note that it will change the font line spacing for not just Visual Studio but also any other application using that font.

Answer (score 4):

As of Visual Studio 2019 (16.10.0) it is now possible to change the line spacing directly in the options under Text Editor => General:

[image]

Comment: A feature apparently designed by someone who's never adjusted the line spacing of their code. Most useful values lie between 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

Can't change directly in Visual studio.
--> **BUT You CAN change line height of font, the font you're using.**
Step 1: install Fontforge.
Step 2: Open Fontforge after install finished, go to:
 Element->Font Info ->OS2 -> Unit.
**Change** 4 value: **Down win, up win, top N, down horizontal** by multiplied by the desired ratio. Sample: ratio 1.5 or 2 ..etc...

(it means: if default 800, you multiple with ratio 1.5 --> result is 1200, you change 800 -->1200)
--> click OK to save setting.
Step 3: Go to File -> Generate font --> Generate with ttf format.
Step 4: Install the font just created and change font in Visual Studio.