# How to implement LineSpacing and Background color of text with a UILabel or UITextview

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel, uitextview, background-color

[image]

How to make one UILabel or UITextView to accomplish that in swift 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set UILabel line spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880526/set-uilabel-line-spacing)

Comment: NSAttributedString + NSBackgroundAttributeName + Line Spacing set to a higher value on potentially a NSParagraphStyle.

Comment: Have you managed to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here solution with Label.

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "How to implement LineSpacing and Background color of text with a UILabel"
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
var style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 24 // change line spacing between paragraph like 36 or 48
style.minimumLineHeight = 20 // change line spacing between each line like 30 or 40
attrString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringValue.characters.count))

// background color
attrString.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringValue.characters.count))

label.attributedText = attrString
```

Answer (score -1):

hello victor u can select textview as attributed,after that u can change textcolor , background color,and line spcing

[image: from bellow image u get idea]