# Swift changing line spacing leaves bottom white space

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am trying to change the line spacing for a label to reduce the line space in Arabic language it is too much. The extension function I used from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880526/set-uilabel-line-spacing) with additions for Arabic styling is working on controlling the line spacing of the label but the only problem it leaves bottom margin white space I assume equals the same label size before reducing the line space.

The extension function here:

```
extension UILabel {
// Pass value for any one of both parameters and see result
func setLineSpacing(lineSpacing: CGFloat = 0.0, lineHeightMultiple: CGFloat = 0.0) {

    guard let labelText = self.text else { return }

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = lineSpacing
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = lineHeightMultiple

    paragraphStyle.alignment = .justified
    paragraphStyle.baseWritingDirection = .rightToLeft

    let attributedString:NSMutableAttributedString

    if let labelattributedText = self.attributedText {
        attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: labelattributedText)
    } else {
        attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: labelText)
    }

    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value:paragraphStyle, range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

    self.attributedText = attributedString
}
```

}

then I just call the function like this:

```
bodyLabel.attributedText = entry.attributedText
bodyLabel.setLineSpacing(lineSpacing: -20)
```

[image]

Comment: Adjust the bottom constraint of your label to >=0 (whatever value you need.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the extension it's working fine like this:

```
bodyLabel.attributedText = entry.attributedText
bodyLabel.setLineSpacing(lineSpacing: -20)
bodyLabel.sizeToFit()
```

Also if that didn't work check the height for the label, and try setting the content to Fill.

```
bodyLabel.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

Answer (score 0):

Constraints of the `bodyLabel` must be like,

[image]

Adjust the `bottom constraint` of your `label` to `>=0`